# Solving an algebraic equation with fractions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, problem-solving

How do I rework the following equation to solve for P when I know the other variables?  (Apologies, I tried to Google but just couldn't get the right search terms.)

T = ( 1/AP - 1/P ) * Q

I got this far, but don't know the next step(s):

T/Q = 1/AP - 1/P

Cheers.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Is it $\dfrac1{A\cdot P}$?  If so, factor out $\dfrac1P$ and/or multiply both sides by $P$

Comment: Here is a guide how to format formulas: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Thanks appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$T = \left(\frac{1}{AP} - \frac{1}{P}\right)\,Q=\frac{Q}{P}\left(\frac{1}{A}-1\right)\,.$$

Then

$$P=\frac{Q}{T}\left(\frac{1}{A}-1\right)\,.$$

Comment: (+1) See J.W. Tanner's answer for the intermediate steps in this solution.